# CSS Line after h2

Tags: css

I need to be able to add a line after an h2 tag which is responsive the titles will be different lengths. Wondering if this is possible via CSS?

Here's my current code:

```
h2:after { 
  border-top: 1px solid #333; 
  content: ""; 
  margin: 0px auto; 
  position: absolute; 
  top: 50%; 
  left: 0px; 
  right: 0px; 
  bottom: 0px; 
  width: 95%; 
  z-index: -1; 
}
```

Comment: yes it's possible. can you show what you have so far

Comment: h2 {
  position: relative;
 }
h2:after {
    border-top: 1px solid #333;
    content: "";
    margin: 0px auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 95%;
    z-index: -1;
 }

Comment: here's an example: [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/jilec/1/) but it might be wrong depending on your current implementation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
h2 {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
h2::after {
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  margin-left: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<h2>Some Text</h2>
<h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur</h2>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to do anything to the heading (h2, etc.):

```css
h2:after {
    width: 40px;
    height: 1px;
    background: #fff;
    position: relative;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    margin: 20px 0;
}
```